# Merge Tag Request: [image-processing] and [image-manipulation]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

[image-processing](/questions/tagged/image-processing) x 6666

[image-manipulation](/questions/tagged/image-manipulation) x 943

[243 questions are tagged with both tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing+image-manipulation)

Both tags are meant to be used for same purpose. And I think they should be merged.

Should tag [image-manipulation](/questions/tagged/image-manipulation) merged into [image-processing](/questions/tagged/image-processing) or not?

**Edit:**
Is there any progress with this request?